# Django: Detect database backend

Tags: database, django, backend, detect

I'm doing some "extra" queries in Django that need to work on both sqlite and postgres. The syntax of these queries varies between backend but I have no way of figuring out if I'm sending my queries to either postgres or sqlite.

Is there a way to get the current database adapter so I can branch my code and send the right query for the active database server?

Comment: queries accept the keyword 'using', where you can select the db where the queries should be performed on. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: the current database always is DATABASES['default'] in settings.py no ? And DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] should contain the engine type.

Comment: I was thinking of a real API instead of checking the settings (like the one proposed in [ticket 18332](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18332)). Checking settings works fine though, would like to mark that as an answer but I can't :)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

OK, so there's two ways of doing it, as @Ricola3D said there's the option of checking `settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']`:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']
'django.db.backends.sqlite3' or 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
```

But there's also an (undocumented) vendor property on a connection:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.vendor
'postgresql' or 'sqlite'
```

Either way works. I personally prefer `connection.vendor` as it looks prettier :)

Comment: Careful when running tests: with a different DB type: `settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']` will still point at the non-testing DB. So `connection.vendor` (or, if you have multiple DBs) `connections[db_name].vendor` is much better, I think