# How to use Django ORM in a join with an aggregate subquery

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model like this (simplified):

```
class Events(models.Model):
    reference_date = models.DateField()
    event = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('reference_date', 'event'),)
```

I can have the same `event` with multiple reference dates, but I only have one `event` per `reference_date`. The table data looks something like this:

| id | reference_date | event | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 12345 | 2022-03-05 18:18:03 | 2022-03-06 18:12:09 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | 12345 | 2022-03-08 08:05:11 | 2022-03-08 08:05:55 |
| 3 | 2022-01-08 | 12345 | 2022-06-15 18:18:12 | 2022-06-16 02:23:11 |
| 4 | 2022-01-01 | 98765 | 2022-01-11 07:55:25 | 2022-01-13 08:45:12 |
| 5 | 2022-01-02 | 98765 | 2022-06-22 10:25:08 | 2022-07-05 18:55:08 |
| 6 | 2022-01-09 | 45678 | 2022-02-19 12:55:07 | 2022-04-16 12:21:05 |
| 7 | 2022-01-10 | 45678 | 2022-03-05 11:23:45 | 2022-03-05 18:55:03 |

I need the latest record for each `event`. But I need all the `event` attributes, not just the `max(reference_date)`

I'm looking for this result:

```
[
{'id': 3, 'event': 12345, 'reference_date': '2022-01-08', 'created_at': '2022-06-15 18:18:12', 'updated_at': '2022-06-16 02:23:11'},
{'id': 5, 'event': 98765, 'reference_date': '2022-01-02', 'created_at': '2022-06-22 10:25:08', 'updated_at': '2022-07-05 18:55:08'},
{'id': 7, 'event': 45678, 'reference_date': '2022-01-10', 'created_at': '2022-03-05 11:23:45', 'updated_at': '2022-03-05 18:55:03'}
]
```

From a 'sql-perspective' I could get the results in multiple ways: SUBQUERIES, ROW_NUMBER, CORRELATED SUBQUERY etc. In this particular case for clarity reasons I prefer to use a join with itself using an aggregate inside the subquery.

If I'd write a raw query, I'd would do like this:

```
SELECT
 e.*
FROM events as e
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
         event,
         max(reference_date) as reference_date
        FROM events
        GROUP BY event) AS b
ON b.reference_date = e.reference_date AND b.event = e.event
```

I think this query is very straightforward and has a good performance for the data volume in this table (hundreds of thousands of records)

I looked for several ways to build this type of query (Subquery, PrefetchRelated etc) but I couldn't find any proper way to translate this query into Django ORM syntax.

Is there a way using the 'django-orm way' without a convoluted ORM solution with the same reasonable performance?

ps: I need this query (or similar ones) for different database engines (PostgreSql, MySQL, MSQLServer ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time with another projects, learning and digging through the Django documentation and other StackOverflow threads, I've discovered a method to retrieve the latest record using the QuerySet API:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Max, F

# Creating the subquery with the last reference date by event
last_event_subquery = (
    Events
    .objects
    .values('event')
    .annotate(last_reference_date = Max('reference_date'))
    .filter(event=OuterRef('event'))
)

# Query to fetch the latest events
latest_events = (
    Events
    .objects
    .annotate(
last_reference_date=Subquery(last_event_subquery.values('last_reference_date'))
    )
    .filter(reference_date=F('last_reference_date'))
)
```

This approach employs the `Max` function in conjunction with `Subquery` and `OuterRef` to retrieve the most recent record for each event.
It then utilizes `F()` expressions to filter and fetch the latest events based on their reference date.

With this queryset I can retrieve all `Event` instance attributes the way I originally wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain this will work, mostly because I mysel haven't had a need (yet) to use this with Django's ORM, but something like this might work. You need to import Max from django.db.models.

I will post this and read up on the docs about `.aggregate()` - read up and still not an expert :).

```
from django.db.models import Max
#Events.objects.all() -> get all the objects from Events
#.group_by("event") tells them to be grouped by the "event" column
#.aggregate(Max("reference_data")) is what I am uncertain about...
Events.objects.all().group_by("event").aggregate(Max("reference_date"))
```

There is also the option to write your raw statement for each db engine and use the `.raw(query)` method on your model to query the database. Since you need support for multiple databases, you could also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20554917/3155240) to determine what database you are using to run the query.

I also came across [this article](https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2009/08/django-aggregation-tutorial/) that influenced the suggestion below:

```
Events.objects.values('event').annotate(Max('reference_date'))
```

Lastly, A SO Post with relatively the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4125463/3155240) mentions using `select_related()` to achieve `JOIN`s.

Comment: Your suggestion only returns the last `reference_date` for each `event`: `['event': 12345, 'reference_date': '2022-01-08'}]`. I need to use this result queryset within a subquery to return all attributes that match those tuples `(event, reference_date)`. I only mentioned that i'm using more than one database to avoid 'PostgreSql only' solutions, because I need those type of queries in different projects with different databases

Comment: But its returning a query set of more than 1 event, correct? And I am assuming you mean the first suggestion?

Comment: Ah, I see... I think I know part of the problem... Do `Events.objects.annotate(Max('reference_date'))` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry. This one: `Events.objects.all().group_by("event").aggregate(Max("reference_date"))` doesn't work:  `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'group_by'` I was talking about this one: `Events.objects.values('event').annotate(Max('reference_date'))` It returns the maximum date (last `reference_date`) for each `event`. It would be the same raw query as : `SELECT event, max(reference_date) as reference_date FROM events GROUP BY event)`. But I need not only the `date` and the `event`, but also the entire set of attributes of this record `id, created_at, updated_at`

Comment: One of the links that you provided answers the aggregation part of the problem. This part is relatively easy to solve in Django. When I 'annotate' a queryset and use an aggregation function (Max, Min, etc) the ORM translate this directly to a grouped set. The other link is about the ORM JOIN, but doesn't really touch the join with subquery problem

Comment: 1st response comment - I'm with you. I think .values() selects the fields, so run it without `.values` or use `.all()`, but with either situation use .annotate, so `Events.objects.all().annotate(Max('reference_date'))` or `Events.objects.annotate(Max('reference_date'))` and (I think) a `.group_by("reference_data")`. 2nd response comment - you could write the subquery in django ORM then run an additional query, but I was uncertain as to how that would affect speed - so I dodged that suggestion in my answer. Thoughts from above?

Comment: In addition to above: Correction - values() returns a dictionary of the objects and attributes as opposed to objects, however, passing it args will return those fields (as a dictionary).

Comment: [1] The first part just groups the events per max reference_date with or without `all()` or `values()`. They return a queryset with the tuples (event , reference_date__max), but the other attributes stay unreachable. [2] My solution today is to use two queries. One to get those pairs (event and reference_date__max) and another query with a big filtered OR and ANDs, similar to this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177749/django-filter-queryset-on-tuples-of-values-for-multiple-columns) but I'm trying to find a more "elegant" solution with the Django ORM

Comment: Well, I tried. I did a search in the django orm docs for "inner" and "join" and (though I'm not certain if its the same join), they are making 2 queries too in their examples.